# WinSound Play sound from variable?

Tags: python

How could I use the `winsound.PlaySound()` function to play with a variable stored instead of a specific sound? I am making a makeshift Music Player and I want to be able to simply play a song that is selected by the user. Here's my current code.

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
import winsound
from Tkconstants import *
from tkFileDialog import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MusicPlayer(Tkinter.Frame):

  def __init__(self, root):

    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)


    # options for buttons
    button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

    #options for images

    # define image
    img = Image.open('musicPlayer.PNG')
    bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label = Tkinter.Label(image=bg)
    label.image = bg
    label.pack()

    # define buttons
    but1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Play', command=self.play)
    but2 = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Stop', command=self.stop)
    but1.grid(sticky="S, W, E", column=1)
    but1.grid(sticky="S, W, E", column=1)   

    # define options for opening or saving a file
    self.file_opt = options = {}
    options['defaultextension'] = '*.wav'
    options['filetypes'] = [('WAV Sound Files', '*.wav')]
    options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
    options['initialfile'] = '.wav'
    options['parent'] = root
    options['title'] = 'Pick a File'

    # This is only available on the Macintosh, and only when Navigation Services are installed.
    #options['message'] = 'message'

    # if you use the multiple file version of the module functions this option is set automatically.
    #options['multiple'] = 1

    # defining options for opening a directory
    self.dir_opt = options = {}
    options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
    options['mustexist'] = False
    options['parent'] = root
    options['title'] = 'Pick a Dir'

  def askopenfile(self):

    return tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r', **self.file_opt)

  def askopenfilename(self):

    # get filename
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)

    # open file on your own
    if filename:
      return open(filename, 'r')
      print filename

  def asksaveasfile(self):

    return tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', **self.file_opt)

  def asksaveasfilename(self):

    # get filename
    filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)

    # open file on your own
    if filename:
      return open(filename, 'w')

  def askdirectory(self):

    return tkFileDialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)

  def play(self):
    soundfile = self.askopenfilename()

    winsound.PlaySound(soundfile, winsound.SND_FILENAME)

  def stop(self):
    winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)

if __name__=='__main__':
  root = Tkinter.Tk()
  root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Python27\DLLs\musicPlayer.ico')
  MusicPlayer(root).pack()
  root.wm_title('Music Player')
  root.mainloop()
```

## Things to Note

- I am new to the winsound plugin, as well as Python itself, and I am not sure which flag I am supposed to use.

## Error I get

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Brenneman.Josh.19\Downloads\code (2)\MusicPlayer.py", line 88, in play
    winsound.PlaySound(soundfile, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not file
```

Comment: What exactly do you want that change to accomplish? Do you want to read in each song file and store it in a variable within the program, rather than simply fetching each file by name to play it? I don't see anything wrong with the way you're asking for a filename and then passing that string to PlaySound().

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It gives me an error about it not being a valid path or string or something like that. I will edit the post with the error.

Comment: You defined your own `askopenfilename` that returns the same thing as the `askopenfile` you defined: a file object. As the traceback says, `winsound.PlaySound()` needs a string with your sound file's path, e.g. `'sounds/mysound.wav'`, not an opened file object. Just use the `tkFileDialog` functions directly instead of wrapping them in your own functions. Does your `asksaveasfilename` function work at all?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't know. Let me try it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  used the direct `tkFileDialog` command and it *sorta* works. It loads the file, and it doesn't give me an error. But when I select the file, it thinks for a second, then makes the Windows `Default Beep` sound, and does nothing else. No error is sent to the console.

Comment: Assuming you have `chimes.wav` in `C:/Windows/Media/`, try the following in a fresh Python interpreter: `import winsound`, then `winsound.PlaySound('C:/Windows/Media/chimes.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)`.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the wrong flag, and that was the problem. Post this as an answer and I'll +1 & accept as answer, @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`winsound`'s `PlaySound()` needs to be passed a string with the filename and one or more flags. I'd recommend the `SND_ASYNC` flag, which plays the sound and returns immediately. Use the following:

```
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Windows/Media/chimes.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```